# is there a android ORM framework?

Tags: android, orm

is there something like a ORM framework for android?

i need this for something like this:

i create some classes and then save them in lists. after this i want to automatically save and load this classes from and to a sqlite database.

Comment: See [this StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3714319/1366455) about this. ORMLite is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ORMLite seems to be the leader in this space, you can check them out here: http://ormlite.com/

It's more lightweight than Hibernate, but works very well on the Android platform.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try Googling "Android ORM"?

The third result will point you to [Any good ORM tools for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371538/any-good-orm-tools-for-android-development)