# refactoring databaseHelper

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm creating a database with this structure (4 Tables):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPaoD.png (Can't embed because lack of rep)

My worries is that the class is growing is in a fast pace and it's not that simple to work in it anymore since it is getting so large. Is there anyway i can refactor (=split it into several classes) my databaseHelper to make it simpler and more structured but yet still make it easy to work with?

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
// Database static variables
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "feedlrDatabase";

// Declaring feed table
private static final String TABLE_FEED = "feed";
private static final String FEED_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
private static final String FEED_COLUMN_NAME = "name";

// Declaring feed-user bridge table
private static final String TABLE_FEEDUSER = "feeduser";
private static final String FEEDUSER_COLUMN_FEED_ID = "feed_ID";
private static final String FEEDUSER_COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_ID";

// Declaring user table
private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";
private static final String USER_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String USER_COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
public static final String USER_COLUMN_USERID = "userid";
public static final String USER_COLUMN_IMGURL = "ProfileImageURL";
public static final String USER_COLUMN_SOURCE = "source";

// Declaring item table
private static final String TABLE_ITEM = "item";
public static final String ITEM_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String ITEM_COLUMN_ITEMID = "itemid";
public static final String ITEM_COLUMN_TEXT = "text";
private static final String ITEM_COLUMN_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
private static final String ITEM_COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
private static final String ITEM_COLUMN_URL = "URL";
private static final String ITEM_COLUMN_IMGURL = "imgURL";
private static final String ITEM_COLUMN_USER_ID = "user_ID";

private SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    // @formatter:off
    // Creating feed table
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FEED + "(" + FEED_COLUMN_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + FEED_COLUMN_NAME
            + " TEXT UNIQUE" + ")");

    // Creating feed-user bridge table
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FEEDUSER + "("
            + FEEDUSER_COLUMN_FEED_ID + " INT NOT NULL,"
            + FEEDUSER_COLUMN_USER_ID + " INT NOT NULL" + ")");

    // Creating user table
    // TODO Should username be the unique idenifier of a user?!
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "(" + USER_COLUMN_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + USER_COLUMN_USERNAME
            + " TEXT NOT NULL," + USER_COLUMN_USERID + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + USER_COLUMN_IMGURL + " TEXT," + USER_COLUMN_SOURCE
            + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ")");

    // Creating item table
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ITEM + "(" + ITEM_COLUMN_ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + ITEM_COLUMN_ITEMID
            + " INT UNIQUE," + ITEM_COLUMN_TEXT + " TEXT,"
            + ITEM_COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DATETIME," + ITEM_COLUMN_TYPE
            + " TEXT," + ITEM_COLUMN_URL + " TEXT," + ITEM_COLUMN_IMGURL
            + " TEXT," + ITEM_COLUMN_USER_ID + " INT NOT NULL" + ")");
    // @formatter:on
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Temporarily drops all tables
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FEED);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FEEDUSER);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ITEM);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void addFeed(Feed feed) {
    ContentValues temp = new ContentValues();

    temp.put(FEED_COLUMN_NAME, feed.getTitle());
    try {
        db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_FEED, null, temp);
    } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Inserted feed is not UNIQUE!");
        // TODO Apply listener to notify the user that the feed name already
        // exists!
    }
}

public void removeFeed(Feed feed) {
    String title = feed.getTitle();
    long id = getFeedID(feed);

    removeFeedBridge(id);

    db.delete(TABLE_FEED, FEED_COLUMN_NAME + "=?", new String[] { title });
}

public ArrayList<String> listFeeds() {
    final ArrayList<String> feeds = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FEED, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String s = c.getString(1);
        feeds.add(s);
    }
    c.close();
    return feeds;
}

public long getFeedID(Feed feed) {
    String feedTitle = feed.getTitle();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_FEED, new String[] { FEED_COLUMN_ID },
            FEED_COLUMN_NAME + "=?", new String[] { feedTitle }, null,
            null, null);
    c.moveToNext();
    Long id = Long.parseLong(c.getString(0));
    c.close();
    return id;
}

public long getUserID(User user) {
    long id = user.getId();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_USER, new String[] { USER_COLUMN_ID },
            USER_COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[] { id + "" }, null, null,
            null);
    c.moveToNext();
    Long id1 = Long.parseLong(c.getString(0));
    c.close();
    return id1;
}

public ArrayList<String> listUsers() {
    final ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER, null);

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String s = c.getString(1);
        users.add(s);
    }
    return users;
}

public void addUserToFeed(User user, Feed feed) {
    long FeedID = getFeedID(feed);
    long UserID = addUser(user);

    // Add bridge connection
    if (UserID != -1) {
        addFeedUserBridge(FeedID, UserID);
    }
}

public long addUser(User user) {
    // TODO Check if the user already exists!!
    ContentValues temp = new ContentValues();

    temp.put(USER_COLUMN_USERNAME, user.getUserName());
    temp.put(USER_COLUMN_USERID, user.getId());
    temp.put(USER_COLUMN_IMGURL, user.getProfileImageURL());
    temp.put(USER_COLUMN_SOURCE, "Twitter");
    // TODO implement source on user?

    long userID = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, temp);
    return userID;
}

public void addFeedUserBridge(long feedID, long userID) {
    ContentValues temp = new ContentValues();

    temp.put(FEEDUSER_COLUMN_FEED_ID, feedID);
    temp.put(FEEDUSER_COLUMN_USER_ID, userID);

    db.insert(TABLE_FEEDUSER, null, temp);
}

public void removeUserFromFeed(Feed feed, User user) {
    long feedID = getFeedID(feed);
    long userID = getUserID(user);

    removeFeedUserBridge(feedID, userID);
}

private void removeUser(User user) {
    long id = user.getId();
    db.delete(TABLE_USER, USER_COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[] { id + "" });
}

private void removeFeedUserBridge(long feedID, long userID) {
    db.delete(TABLE_FEEDUSER, FEEDUSER_COLUMN_FEED_ID + "=?" + " and "
            + FEEDUSER_COLUMN_USER_ID + "=?", new String[] { feedID + "",
            userID + "" });
}

public ArrayList<String> listFeedUser() {
    final ArrayList<String> feeduser = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FEEDUSER, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        feeduser.add(c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1));
    }
    c.close();
    return feeduser;
}

private void removeFeedBridge(Long id) {
    db.delete(TABLE_FEEDUSER, FEEDUSER_COLUMN_FEED_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { id + "" });
}

public void updateUser(long userID) {
    // TODO implement this method
}

public void addListOfItems(List<? extends Item> itemList) {
    db.beginTransaction();
    for (Item i : itemList) {
        ContentValues temp = new ContentValues();
        temp.put(ITEM_COLUMN_ITEMID, i.getId());
        temp.put(ITEM_COLUMN_TEXT, i.getText());
        temp.put(ITEM_COLUMN_TIMESTAMP, i.getTimestamp());
        temp.put(ITEM_COLUMN_TYPE, i.getText());
        temp.put(ITEM_COLUMN_URL, i.getURL());
        temp.put(ITEM_COLUMN_IMGURL, i.getIMGURL());
        temp.put(ITEM_COLUMN_USER_ID, i.getUser().getId());
        db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_ITEM, null, temp, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);

    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
}

public List<User> getUsersInFeed(Feed feed) {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    Cursor c = db
            .rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER + " WHERE "
                    + USER_COLUMN_USERID + " IN (SELECT "
                    + FEEDUSER_COLUMN_USER_ID + " FROM " + TABLE_FEEDUSER
                    + " WHERE " + FEEDUSER_COLUMN_FEED_ID + " = "
                    + getFeedID(feed) + ")", null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        users.add(new User(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(USER_COLUMN_USERID)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(USER_COLUMN_USERNAME))));
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    return users;
}

public Cursor getAllItems() {
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_ITEM, new String[] { ITEM_COLUMN_ID,
            ITEM_COLUMN_TEXT, ITEM_COLUMN_TIMESTAMP, ITEM_COLUMN_TYPE,
            ITEM_COLUMN_URL, ITEM_COLUMN_IMGURL, ITEM_COLUMN_USER_ID },
            null, null, null, null, null);
    // db.close();
    return c;
}

public long getItemTableSize() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    long l = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(database, TABLE_ITEM);
    // database.close();
    return l;
}

public void clearItemTable() {
    db.delete(TABLE_ITEM, null, null);
}

public void clearUserTable() {
    db.delete(TABLE_USER, null, null);
}

public void clearFeeds() {
    db.delete(TABLE_FEED, null, null);
    db.delete(TABLE_FEEDUSER, null, null);
}

public void addUsers(List<? extends User> users) {
    db.beginTransaction();

    for (User u : users) {
        ContentValues temp = new ContentValues();
        temp.put(USER_COLUMN_USERNAME, u.getUserName());
        temp.put(USER_COLUMN_USERID, u.getId());
        temp.put(USER_COLUMN_SOURCE, u.getSource());
        db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_USER, null, temp, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
}

public Cursor getAllUsers() {
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_USER, new String[] { USER_COLUMN_ID,
            USER_COLUMN_USERNAME, USER_COLUMN_USERID }, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    return c;
}

public Cursor getItems(Feed feed) {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ITEM 
            + " WHERE " + ITEM_COLUMN_USER_ID 
            + " IN (SELECT " + FEEDUSER_COLUMN_USER_ID 
            + " FROM " + TABLE_FEEDUSER
            + " WHERE " + FEEDUSER_COLUMN_FEED_ID 
            + " = " + getFeedID(feed)
            + ") ORDER BY " + ITEM_COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC", null);
    return c;
}
```

}

Best regards
Rawa

Comment: Please format your Big Blob of Code.

Comment: Honestly, this really isn't that big. Even at 20 tables it's not that big.  With that being said, perhaps moving your column definition into domain models could help organize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider replacing your hand-crafted JBDC code with an [Object Relational Mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software)

See: [ORM on Android SQLite and database scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973982/orm-on-android-sqlite-and-database-scheme)

Comment: Seems like ORM would be a nice choice for me in my situation. I might have to consider using it instead, however is there anyway to refactor my current database?

Comment: Thanks for the accept. To answer your question, your database schema is already pretty simple and normalized.