# Android ORM Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, orm

I am doing some research for techniques for future apps and am interested in Object databases and would to know more about those for the android platform.

Can someone point me in the right direction, for any good ones and the pros and cons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to see you are trying new things, maybe this topic will provide you with some more info:[orm-on-android-sqlite-and-database-scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973982/orm-on-android-sqlite-and-database-scheme)